# uibModal Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Não estou conseguindo passar via `$ctrl.close(data)` para a `controller` que usa esse `component`:

uibModal que estou utilizando:

```
angular.module('sisApcd').component('buscaPessFis', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/buscaPessFis/pessFisBusca.html',
    bindings: {
        resolve: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    },

    /// Controller do Component de buscaPessFis
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        };

        // Acoes click
        $scope.ok = function (e) {
            var valor = e.target.attributes['id-user'].value;
            $ctrl.close({valor2: 'teste'});
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $ctrl.dismiss({valor2: 'teste'});
        };
    }
});
```

Onde chama o componente:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

E me retorna

> undefined

Comment: Eu ia fazer uma resposta mas estou sem tempo, mas você precisa usar o `$modalInstance.close`, caso esteja usando versão atualizada é `$uibModalInstance.close`, e para usar você precisa injetar no controller `function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) { ... }`